# Get WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri outside the Runtime

Tags: c#, oauth, windows-runtime, oauth-2.0, windows-8.1

We can get the current application callback URI by using the  `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri` method on Windows 8.1 Store Apps. Is there any way to get this application callback URI outside the runtime?

I need the application callback URI to register my client to the OAuth 2.0 provider I'm using right now. They validate the Redirect URI and if it doesn't match the one that you registered, the handshake fails.

Comment: What do you mean outside the Runtime? Like, you want a user to be able to enter it manually into a website and need to figure out a method of giving them access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.zubairahmed.net/?p=2021) article you need to register your app in Windows Dev Center to get that uri.